# Why is the Java compiler designed to apparently not interrogate assignment of final variables through try-catch?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, try-catch, variable-assignment, final

Why was the Java compiler (way back, 1997, 1995?) designed not to evaluate assignment of final variables in the presence of try-catch? If is fully designed to ensure assignment (or not) through if, switch, while, through method calls ... but not through try-catch in my example.

```
final boolean myFinal;

try {
  myFinal = true;

} catch (final Exception e) {

  myFinal = false;
}
```

In this most simplistic example, myFinal is determined to maybe not be assigned.

On the surface there is nothing to stop myFinal being assigned true.

What is the reasoning behind this?

This lot gives us the compiler rules, but not the rationale behind them except the high level philosophy of assignment/un-assignment:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.15

It's obviously not about Exception being thrown by code inside the try block, as there is nothing that throws any exceptions at all - checked or not.

Could it be that while a thread is inside that try block, exceptions that could occur on that thread, maybe OOM or other low-level issues, could be thrown, and thus the compiler cannot be sure if the isValid := true had actually happened or not?

I'm after a reason beyond "that is the way it is" ... Java was given massive thought and rigor to its compiler, there's clearly a significant decision made here over how this is handled in try-catch. Just need to know what it is.

Rich

Comment: The only ones who know for sure, are those who designed the compiler and got to make that choice

Comment: What you suggest is that the compiler does static code analysis to see if there is a possible (runtime) exception? Wouldn't that be a performance nightmare? Also I like the consistency. Would it add to language simplicity if your case was forbidden but by adding a single object access `obj.toString()` it would suddenly be allowed (because of possible NPE)?

Comment: "n this most simplistic example, myFinal is determined to maybe not be assigned." That's not what my compiler says. But what I see is that you declare a variable final and then make it possible for it to be assigned more than once. Of course that will be rejected.

Comment: As mentioned by @kumesana, the error here is a [double initialization](https://tio.run/##VY2xEoIwEET7fMWWUOgPOJbaWVE6FkcIGAwJkxyMDMO3x3PUwupm9@2b62mmXd88snaUEi5k/arGqXZWIzGxnDnYBoOAouJofXe9gWKXyjW31pNDHYIz5DEs53c@KMVxwarwa3AEx8kI2KCJ9R3Fxzw9tRnZBg9TivBntOSSKFuulsRm2IeJ96O8Z@eL76oUvOUX)

Comment: "On the surface there is nothing to stop myFinal being assigned true.": 1) Another thread interrupting the current one before/in the middle of the assignment. 2) JVM crash/termination/magic

Comment: btw, `Exception` isn't the parent of all exceptions. It could be any `Error` or `Throwable` being thrown.

Comment: What is the compiler error that you are getting? I am getting "error: variable myFinal might already have been assigned" which seems correct behaviour.

Comment: >As mentioned by @kumesana, the error here is a double initialization
I know what happens - I'm asking _why_ the compiler rules are designed this way.

Comment: >btw, Exception isn't the parent of all exceptions. It could be any Error or Throwable being thrown.
I know this - the rules are the same for Throwable as well.

Comment: >which seems correct behaviour.
I know - but i'm asking WHY this is the behaviour, not what the behavour is.

Comment: Can I ask please that we try to answer the "why" part of this question, not just reel off what the JVM does and does not do. I know what it does, but i'm thinking on a higher level than _what_ and i'm onto the _why_.

Comment: >"On the surface there is nothing to stop myFinal being assigned true.": 1) Another thread interrupting the current one before/in the middle of the assignment. 2) JVM crash/termination/magic

Yes these are things I've considered. But I cannot find any source of truth yet. I guess at the moment they are possibilities, sure.

Comment: @Stultuske I agree ... how does one go about finding this out? I am wondering whether it was something like:

Option A) "We _could_ do this in our compiler but it's a lot of work, can only work in certain circumstances, and and we want to get the languages finalised sooner rather than later."

Option B) "Impossible because of X logic that happens when Y occurs" (where we don't know what X and Y are but the language and compiler writers do)

Comment: @RichColours the best options are: read texts written by the original designers on the topic, or, talk to the original designers of the language. all the rest is speculation and opinion.

Comment: why what? You claim that with the given code you obtain a specific error message ("might not have been assigned a value"). The given code doesn't produce that error message at all. It complains that you assign a value more than once, to a variable made final and which therefore you demanded cannot be assigned more than once.